# Is Alagaesia a climatically realistic world?

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, map-making

[https://inheritance.fandom.com/wiki/Alagaësia](https://inheritance.fandom.com/wiki/Alaga%C3%ABsia)

[image: ALAGAESIA MAP]

https://www.paolini.net/2017/11/10/map-alagaesia-prints-2017/

Looking at the map, you have a tropical desert at around the same latitudes as Urubaen. Also, the desert borders directly with a huge forest, and most of this forest has tropical characteristics.

I don't know why, but something in my head screams WRONG at this.

Comment: sorry, I don't get your reference. Is there supposed to be a map her?

Comment: This sounds like a question about the aspect of an already existing world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. No it is not in the slightest. Though it does slightly get right (assuming it is in the westerly cell) the affect of the mountains rain shadow creating a desert. However the desert is much too big and far away from the mountains. The desert should be nestled right up to the mountains with it transitioning to grassland the further east you go.

The forest right on a desert is nonsense.

(PS: This question is probably not quite right for this site as it does not deal with your own world building.)